# how to change the text color of currently open link and remain default color of unopened link?so user gets an idea on which link he is currently on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

i want to change the color of text which is active ..so that the user have an idea that  which page he using....for example we have 2 hyberlink of  HOME and ABOUT pages..i want when i clicked on HOME link its color changes(i.e green) and other menu items like ABOUT will remain in default color(i.e red)..and when i clicked on ABOUT menu then its text should change(i.e green) and ASLO HOME menu will kept its default color(i.e red), 
i want this on sidebar of wordpress(with in text plugin/widget) where i gave hyperlink of 2 different pages so i would be better if it get HTML and CSS code or any other suggestion will be appreciated
hope you guyes will understand my question, Thanks in advance for Helping me , Will wait for positive response thanks

Comment: Please post HMTL for the link section, and CSS for that that you already have

Answer (score 2):

Check out the CSS selectors `:active`, `:hover`, `:link`, and `:visited`.

- **`:active`** select and style the active link
- **`:hover`** selects and styles a link with the user hovers over it
- **`:link`** selects and styles a link that hasn't been visited
- **`:visited`** selects and styles a link that has been visited

A `:hover` selector **must** cover after a `:link` and `:visited` selector.
Also, an `:active` selector **must** come after a `:hover` selector.

You would use these like this:

```
a:link {
    color: red;
}

a:visited {
    color: green;
}

a:hover {
    color: blue;
}

a:active {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Check out this article: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: This is probably a better reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Useful_CSS_tips/Links Otherwise +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it's done in Wordpress, but generally speaking this is how you could do it when you have to work with php includes:

for every page you define a variable containing the page name, for example, in the about page you define something like

`<?php $page = "about"; ?>`

and in the Home page you'd have

`<?php $page = "home"; ?>`

Then inside the navigation you'd check what the `$page` value is and echo a "active" class name for the link. I hope this explains it:

```
<li><a href="home.php" class="<?php $page == "home" ? "active" : "" ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php" class="<?php $page == "about" ? "active" : "" ?>">About</a></li>
```

What this does is: it checks the value of the `$page` variable declared in the page and adds a "active" class to the anchor tag if the value matches, otherwise it leaves the class name blank.

And then in your CSS you'd have the styles for the class `.active` like for example:

```
.active{ color: green; }
```

The point is that you need to make sure that the "current" page's anchor has a class (usually an "active" or "current" class, but you can name it anything you want), and then using php you check the name of the page as I mentioned above and then add that class name to the anchor (or list item, whatever works for you).

I'm not sure how you'd go about that in Wordpress, but maybe you could use the above technique and customize it somehow to fit your needs. (like if it's a custom widget you made you could use that)

Hope that helped.